# Pong Game: Paddle Won't Move with Input (Python)

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle, pong

I am a novice to Python trying to make the game Pong. I have created a  Paddle class with the Turtle Graphics module, but I can't get the paddle to move. I just want to start with one direction and then down shouldn't be too hard from there. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong with my method?

```
from turtle import Turtle

COORDINATES = [(350, 20), (350, 0), (350, -20)]
X_COORDINATES = [350, 350, 350]
Y_COORDINATES = [20, 0, -20]


class Paddle(Turtle):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.paddle = []
        self.create_paddles()
        self.coordinate_number = 0

    def create_paddles(self):
        for coordinates in COORDINATES:
            self.paddle_block = Turtle(shape='square')
            self.paddle_block.goto(coordinates)
            self.paddle_block.color('white')
            self.paddle.append(self.paddle_block)

    def w(self):
        global Y_COORDINATES
        Y_COORDINATES = [coordinate + 100 for coordinate in Y_COORDINATES]

        for self.paddle_block in self.paddle:
            self.paddle_block.goto(X_COORDINATES[self.coordinate_number], Y_COORDINATES[self.coordinate_number])
            self.coordinate_number += 1
        self.coordinate_number = 0
```

I tried to iterate through the y-coordinates and add to each of them with my function. From there, I tried to iterate through each paddle block and move it's current location to a new one, taking in the newly updated y coordinate. I expect movement, but I am not seeing any movement whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the usual approach to this problem, but I can see why it might be advantageous.  Your primary issue seems to be not being able to determine what should be *global*, what should be *local*, and what should be a *property*.  Let's make this work to demonstrate the use of all three:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

COORDINATES = [(350, 20), (350, 0), (350, -20)]

class Paddle(Turtle):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.paddle = []
        self.coordinates = list(COORDINATES)  # make copy

        self.create_paddles()

    def create_paddles(self):
        for coordinate in self.coordinates:
            paddle_block = Turtle(shape='square', visible=False)
            paddle_block.penup()
            paddle_block.color('white')
            paddle_block.goto(coordinate)
            paddle_block.showturtle()

            self.paddle.append(paddle_block)

    def move_up(self):
        self.coordinates = [(x, y + 10) for x, y in self.coordinates]

        for coordinate_number, paddle_block in enumerate(self.paddle):
            paddle_block.goto(self.coordinates[coordinate_number])

    def move_down(self):
        self.coordinates = [(x, y - 10) for x, y in self.coordinates]

        for coordinate_number, paddle_block in enumerate(self.paddle):
            paddle_block.goto(self.coordinates[coordinate_number])

screen = Screen()
screen.bgcolor('black')

paddle_1 = Paddle()

screen.onkey(paddle_1.move_up, 'w')
screen.onkey(paddle_1.move_down, 's')

screen.listen()
screen.mainloop()
```